# Actors make my computer hang

Tags: scala, akka

The following code makes my computer hang all the time:

```
object Application extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props[Supervisor])
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

  import system.dispatcher

  val future = supervisor ? Supervisor.Start
  val idList = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[List[MyClass]]
  supervisor ! idList
}
```

It causes an exception of `timeout` but later when it barely responds. Previously, when this code didn't use actors, everything worked just fine.

I can't post of it because there is a lot of it. What code do I have to post?

**UPDATE**:

how do I find out where the problem is?

Comment: does it hang the computer (i.e. the OS), or just the java process?

Comment: @Bathsheba, it's hard to say. anyway, I end up rebooting.

Comment: What do you mean by hang the process? What I think you probably mean is that the application does not terminate?

Comment: @Jatin, I have to reboot the computer to stop it.

Comment: The code you show is completely innocuous and normal: in order to help you we’d need to know what Supervisor does! (my guess is that it goes into some infinite loop or creates a Supervisor as a child—recursively).

Comment: @RolandKuhn, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not terminating your `Actorsystem` and hence the application does not terminate.
At the end you need to call `system.shutdown` which will shutdown the `ActorSystem`.

Internally `ActorSystem` manages threads which needs to be terminated for the application to terminate. `shutdown` terminates them. Not calling it will prevent your application from shutting down as the threads will still be alive.

Comment: You can also call system.awaitTermination after shutdown, since shutdown is asynchronous.